# Is there a simpler way to preform projection on a ListItemCollection?

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, webforms, projection

G'day all,
Is there a way to preform projection on the contents of a list box. 
Specifically I'd like to be able to do it without having to clear and add back the contents of my listbox
This is what I currently have.

```
public static void SetSelectedWhere(this ListBox listbox, Func<ListItem,bool> condition) 
{
   var queryableList = listbox.Items.Cast<ListItem>();
   queryableList.Select(x=>condition(x)?x.Selected:x.Selected=false);
   listbox.Items.Clear();
   listbox.Items.AddRange(queryableList.ToArray<ListItem>());
}
```

and it seems silly to have to clear out my existing collection and add the contents back.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about plain old iteration?

```
foreach (ListItem item in listbox.Items)
{
    item.Selected = condition(item);
}
```

LINQ is not the answer to life the universe and everything. Particularly that part of the universe that involves setting properties on existing objects.

Comment: I'd say that depends, LINQ makes me happy, which seems a good answer to life at least ;-)

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: My way of saying that is "LINQ makes me feel I am a ninja" ;-)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile since `.Items` returns an object enumeration - not a strongly typed `ListItem`.

Comment: @Joshua: Aren't we talking about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) `ListBox`?

Comment: Well son of a... \*sees `asp.net-webforms` tag\*. Yes, yes we are. Don't mind me~~

Comment: @Joshua: I edited it anyway just to be sure. `var` => `ListItem` for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

It is silly to remove and read the items in the collection since it is completely unnecessary.

You should be able to simplify it to the following:

```
foreach (ListItem item in listbox.Items)) {
  item.Selected = condition(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listbox.Items
      .Cast<ListItem>()
           .Where(x=> condition(x))
                .ToList()
                      .ForEach(item => item.Selected = true);
```

`List<T>` has a method called `ForEach` and you can perform an action for any of the items in the list:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx